# Convert jcharArray to String with right encoding jni

Tags: java, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have native method that return array of files in directory.
public static native char[][] scan(String path);
I can't return array of strings because if file has invalid encoding- everything crashes
The problem is correctly convert char[] to String on java side, when i try new String(chars); i get unprintable string (invalid). Please correct me.

Here is example of output (If method return String[])

`Array.toString(scan("/storage/"));` -> [/storage/sdcard1, /storage/sdcard0]

Here is if method return char[][];

```
char[][] chars = scan("/storage/");
String[] stringArray = new String[char.length];
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    stringArray[i] = new String(char[i]);
}
Arrays.toString(stringArray); -> //unprintable symbols [����������爀条⽥摳慣摲쉮R����,����������爀条⽥摳慣摲쉮R����]
```

What happens on C side: if method return String[]

```
jobjectArray scan(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls,jstring jpath){
    std::vector<std::string> data;//contains some strings
    unsigned int size = data.size();
    jobjectArray ret = env->NewObjectArray(size,env->FindClass("java/lang/String"),NULL);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret,i,env->NewStringUTF(data.at(i).c_str()));
        }
    return ret;
}
```

What happens on C side: if method return char[][];

```
jobjectArray scan(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls,jstring jpath){
        std::vector<std::string> data;//contains some strings
        unsigned int size = data.size();
        jobjectArray ret = env->NewObjectArray(size, env->FindClass("[C"), NULL);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret,i,env->NewStringUTF(toChar(env,data.at(i))));
            }
        return ret;
    }
    jcharArray toChar(JNIEnv *env, string string) {
        unsigned int n=0;
        const char* p = string.c_str();
        while(*p++){
            n++;
        } if(n<=0)
            return NULL;

        jcharArray arr = env->NewCharArray(n);
        env->SetCharArrayRegion(arr,0,n, (jchar*)p);
        return arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `NewStringUTF` on non-MUTF8 strings (where MUTF8 is the "modified UTF-8" defined by the JNI spec).

You either need to convert the local character set to UTF-16 in native code and then use `NewString`, or pass arrays of `byte[]` into your Java code and then use the [String constructor that takes a charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) argument.  The Charset to use depends on what your filesystem supports.

Right now you're either putting non-MUTF8 data into `NewStringUTF`, which will fail noisily if CheckJNI is enabled, or you're putting byte values into UTF-16 chars without doing a charset conversion.

Comment: I tried byte[] also (instead of char[]), with different charsets(utf-8, utf-16, us-ansii), result is unreadable file names. That is the problem.

Comment: You need to find the charset that matches your filesystem.  Do you know what charset it's using?  If you're not sure, add a hex dump of some problematic filenames (along with the expected appearance) to the question and perhaps someone will recognize it.  Start with something simple, e.g. a name that's just ASCII characters with something unusual in the middle.  (And if the filenames *are* all ASCII, then something else is going on.)